Extracting Working Hours Between Two Dates in BigQuery
I have the following BigQuery script:
WITH test_table AS (
 SELECT
 CAST('2024-05-02 10:00:00' AS DATETIME) AS start_date,
 CAST('2024-05-06 11:00:00' AS DATETIME) AS end_date

)

SELECT
DATETIME_DIFF(end_date,start_date, second ),
(SELECT 
 COUNT(*) 
 FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(DATE(start_date), DATE(end_date)))  dt
 WHERE EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM dt) BETWEEN 6 AND 2
)


FROM test_table

I am trying to work out the working hours and minutes as a decimal, between two dates, and excluding weekends. I am new to BigQuery, and normally I'd handle this as a function, but I cannot do that with our GCP setup.
Essentially I need to work out the working hours between two dates, exclude any weekends, and keep in mind that a working date is between 8:00 and 17:00.
You'll see I am trying the generate_date_array to do this, but how can I account for start and end time as part of the calc? Essentially I cannot have more than 8 hours per working day?
There is a further requirement, and that is to exclude any time between 12:00 and 13:00 (lunch break), but I first want to see how I can do this before adding that kind of complexity.

For me ... I'd write down a pseudo code algorithm (irrespective of SQL) that takes an input the start date/time and end date/time and calculates your result.  This is the LOGIC you want to implement.  From there, we can think of how to implement this.  One notion is to use a User Defined Function which can be written in JavaScript.  BigQuery has UDFs ... but I heard you say "I can't do that it in our GCP setup" ... my question then is "why?".

Here's how you solve your question:

Create an array of all hours in each day between the start and end datetimes, using GENERATE_TIMESTAMP_ARRAY.
UNNEST the array so we get one row per hour per day.
Work out if that day is a working day (weekday) or not using DAYOFWEEK. Note that in BigQuery, the week starts on a Sunday (day 1) and ends on a Saturday (day 7). Use EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM <field>) BETWEEN 2 AND 6 i.e. Mon-Fri.
Work out if the hour in the day is a working hour (7-12 or 13-17) using EXTRACT(HOUR FROM <field>) BETWEEN ... AND .... If true, we want the number of minutes for that hour (60), else we exclude it (set counting minutes as 0).
Combine (3) and (4), using a CASE statement so we can evaluate the conditions from (3) and (4) and set the number of qualifying minutes. Note that we need (3) and either of (4)'s conditions to be true, so we need to wrap the OR from (4) in parentheses because we have both an AND and an OR. e.g. take all of (3) AND (condition1 for (4) OR condition2 for (4) ).
Finally we can sum the number of contributing minutes and work that out as hours by dividing by 60. This gives us 24.0 hours.

WITH
  test_table AS (
    SELECT
      CAST('2024-05-02 10:00:00' AS TIMESTAMP) AS start_date,
      CAST('2024-05-06 11:00:00' AS TIMESTAMP) AS end_date
  ),

  splitout AS (
    SELECT dt, 
      EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM dt) AS dayofweek,
      EXTRACT(HOUR FROM dt) AS clockhour,
      CASE
        WHEN 
          EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM dt) BETWEEN 2 AND 6 --2 means Monday and 6 means Friday` --condition 1
          AND
          (
            EXTRACT(HOUR FROM dt) BETWEEN 7 AND 12 --AM working hours: condition 2A
            OR
            EXTRACT(HOUR FROM dt) BETWEEN 13 AND 17 --PM working time --condition 2B
          )
          THEN 60 --assign 60 contributing minutes if both conditions 1 and either of 2A or 2B are true
        ELSE 0 --if 1 or both conditions are false, assign 0 working minutes
      END AS working_time
    FROM
      test_table AS t,
      UNNEST(GENERATE_TIMESTAMP_ARRAY(t.start_date, t.end_date, INTERVAL 1 HOUR)) AS dt
  )

--Sum the working minutes and convert to hours
SELECT
  SUM(working_time)/60 AS total_hours
FROM
  splitout;

I suspect that I am overcounting by 60 minutes as the hour of the end_date is counting as "worked", so it overcounts by 60 mins.
If the end_date time is a hard stop, i.e. work ends at NN:59:59 of the previous hour, then yes it is overcounting. If that end_date time is the last "valid hour" i.e. it counts until HH:59:59 of that hour, then it is correct.
